# Where to begin debugging GTK anomaly?

Tags: debugging, gtk, gimp, display-manager

Recently installed Linux Mint 21 Mate Edition.
Then installed Gimp 2.10.30 from their repos.

Gimp has two modes of operation: single and multi-window.
Default is single window. A quick operational test in single
window mode showed normal operations for everything I tried.

from the Gimp main menu I chose Windows and then uncheck
Single-Window checkbox - ie to go to multi-window mode.

I am immediately dumped out of my current user session,
I have to log back in.

These lines are in lightdm.log right after tripping
session closure. But not sure of where to go from here.

```
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: Process 18762 terminated with signal 6
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: XServer 0: X server stopped
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: Releasing VT 7
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: XServer 0: Removing X server authority /var/run/lightdm/root/:0
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Display server stopped
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Stopping session
[+33453.16s] DEBUG: Terminating login1 session c10
[+33453.17s] DEBUG: Session pid=18835: Sending SIGTERM
[+33453.17s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Active display server stopped, starting greeter
[+33453.17s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating greeter session
[+33453.17s] DEBUG: Seat seat0: Creating display server of type x
[+33453.17s] DEBUG: Using VT 7
```

Comment: To report this as a Gimp bug, see [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/-/issues/). Latest Gimp is 2.10.32.

Comment: I'd suggest to report this to Mint first.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out an update to a driver for Intel HD graphics
has deprecated some older chipsets.

I found a work-around on the Ubuntu Community Forums.
The relevant discussion can be found here:
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/browser-consistently-crashes-mate-desktop-session/25855/15
https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-mate-22-04-auto-ending-sessions-when-i-do-something-specific/25897/25
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/intel_graphics#Tearing

I was attempting to install on an old HP Pavilion laptop that uses
an i915 chipset that is no longer supported by this driver.

Work-around involves placing a configuration file named 20-intel.conf
into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ containing the following lines:

Section "Device"
Identifier "Intel Graphics"
Driver "intel"
Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection

This solves the immediate problems I have bee observing.

Thanks to all for your replies.
And to all involved in finding and publishing the work-around.